# Taking a camera picture and saving the path to a database, then using it to populate an ImageView

Tags: android, sqlite, camera

I am trying to take a snapshot with the camera, grab the path of the returned bitmap, then use that link to populate an ImageView.  Everything seems to be working except that the ImageView is blank when I run the emulator.  Here are some of the code snippets I have so far.

Here is my database code:

```
//constants for notes table

    public static final String NOTES_TABLE = "note";
    public static final String NOTES_ID = "noteId";
    public static final String ACTUAL_NOTE = "theNotes";
    public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "imagePath";

  //Create notes table
    public static final String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + NOTES_TABLE + " (" + NOTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ACTUAL_NOTE + " TEXT, " + COURSE_ID + " INTEGER, "
            +  IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT" + ")";
```

This is the code to take a photo:

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = new File(this.getExternalCacheDir(),
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NoteViewActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_TAKE_PHOTO);

}
```

This it the code that returns the photo data and saves the path to my database

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        final long noteNo = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_NOTENO);
        DBOpenHelper helper = new DBOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NoteViewActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                file);
        String pathToImage = fileUri.toString();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.IMAGE_PATH, pathToImage);
        db.update(DBOpenHelper.NOTES_TABLE, cv, DBOpenHelper.NOTES_ID + "=" + noteNo, null);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

Finally this is the code I'm using to populate the ImageView:

```
    //Create a cursor
    DBOpenHelper helper = new DBOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.NOTES_TABLE, new String[]{
                    DBOpenHelper.NOTES_ID,
                    DBOpenHelper.ACTUAL_NOTE,
                    DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID,
                    DBOpenHelper.IMAGE_PATH},
            DBOpenHelper.NOTES_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(noteNo)}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //Get all the info to populate TextViews
        String actualNote = cursor.getString(1);
        if (cursor.getString(3) != null){
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(3);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

        //Populate first textview
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_edittext1);
        textView1.setText(actualNote);

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
```

Thank you so much in advance.  I've been working on this camera problem for way too long so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: maybe the imageview is not instantiated to the correct imageview id? or perhaps the bitmap cannot find the file (or no access permission) to load as bitmap?

Comment: @vimsliu I can't seem to get it to work :[

Comment: hmm, seems I am having trouble with running the code with the FileProvider approach, perhaps you could try imageView.setimageUri(Uri) where uri is the result from FileProvider where the file = new File(get external cache dir, image name) or maybe just (if you are sure the path is correct AND THE IMAGES ARE INDEED IN THE SAID PATH[did you check?]) Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath ))

Comment: and i believe that the getexternalcachedir should be used like this:
file = new File(new File(ImageStoreTestActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "images"),
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
where "images" is one of the path value specified in xml
base on the steps from android dev site: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html